# Посчитать статистику

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы `articles(id, section_id)` и `sections(id)` связанные соответственно связью один ко многим (одна секция имеет много статей). Я хочу узнать сколько минимально, в среднем и максимально статей во всех секциях. Не доводилось делать таких агрегирующих запросов с `MIN, MAX, AVG`... Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В первую очередь придётся посчитать статьи:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id)
FROM Articles a
GROUP BY a.section_id
```

Из этого можно получить агрегаты:

```
SELECT min(agg.cnt) mincnt, max(agg.cnt) maxcnt, avg(agg.cnt) avgcnt
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(a.id) cnt
  FROM Articles a
  GROUP BY a.section_id
) agg
```